# Pinvoke a VB6 function from C#.Net 2010

Tags: c#, vb6, pinvoke

I want to PInvoke a function written in VB6 from C#. We can call this function in VB6 like this:

```
Declare Function ApplyNNet Lib " location of the DLL file" (MyNNetType As String, MyAddress As String, MyInput() As Double) As Variant
```

My code in C# is:

```
[DllImport("NNetApply.dll", EntryPoint = "ApplyNNet", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern IntPtr ApplyNNet(string type, string add, double[,] data);
//run ANN with data
string address = @"C:\Users\PNGE-User\Desktop\Faegheh\Project\Neural Network For Pressure Vs q,x,y\P ve x,y,q\P ve x,y,q";
        double[,] P = new double[no_data,2];
        var P_ = ApplyNNet("Back Prop", address, data);
```

When I debug my code, an error appears:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: VB.NET or VB (e.g. VB6, VBA)?

Comment: Why did you tag your question as VB.NET?  Is your first example showing how you call the function from a VB.NET project?

Comment: @StevenDoggart: oh no it is just a mistake! i wanna call a vb function in C# 2010.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: the things I know are the parameters type that is mentiones above. I call ApplyNNet with 2 strings and a 2D matrix of doubles(data):    var P_ = ApplyNNet("Back Prop", address, data);

Comment: Please show the C# declaration of the function. And also how you create all the parameters to the function. We cannot help you until you do that.

Comment: VB6 could not create "standard" .DLL files, so I'm not sure you will be able to make a pinvoke call to it.  You should be able to add a reference to the VB6 .dll on the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog  and access its classes and methods that way.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway There aren't classes. The use of `Declare Function` indicates that this is a plain native DLL.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I also added this dll on the COM and my references. but I couldn't call is's function in my codes. it was not accessible, so some one said i should pinvoke my dll.

Comment: Can you show how the function is declared in VB6?  I'm with @ChrisDunaway, I didn't think it was possible to make a non-COM dll in VB6.

Comment: @StevenDoggart The function clearly wasn't written in VB6. The fact that it can be called from VB6 using `Declare Function` makes that clear.

Comment: Put it in the question rather than in comments. It's not good in comments. Do you know how to edit a question?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan oh yeah, and tnx for your editing ;)

Comment: The first sentence of the question is wrong and has caused much confusion. Clearly the DLL was not created with VB6. But you are calling it from VB6. I suggest another edit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - The OP in a comment said they were able to add a reference on the COM tab so that muddies the waters as to whether this is a native .dll or a COM .dll.

Comment: @FaeghehJavadi - Can you clarify whether or not this .dll (NNetApply.dll) was created with VB6 or something else?  Also, see the discussion at this link, maybe it will help:  http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/276598

Comment: @ChrisDunaway: I have not write this dll but in the tutorial it is said that it's written in vb and can be called in vb like the one I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I am assuming that the DLL was not in fact written in VB6. The fact that you show code that uses `Declare` to call the function contradicts that. So I am assuming that the DLL was written in some other language (e.g. C++) and that you are currently calling the DLL from VB6.

The VB6 code that calls the DLL is declared like this:

```
Declare Function ApplyNNet Lib "DLLFileName" (MyNNetType As String,
    MyAddress As String, MyInput() As Double) As Variant
```

Your C# version looks like this:

```
[DllImport("NNetApply.dll", EntryPoint = "ApplyNNet", 
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)] 
public static extern IntPtr ApplyNNet(string type, string add, double[,] data);
```

There are two obvious differences:

1. The third parameter does not match. Instead of `double[,]` you need `double[]`.
2. The return value does not match. A VB6 variant cannot be matched up with `IntPtr`. You need to declare the return value to be of type `object` in your C# code.

So the pinvoke should be:

```
[DllImport("NNetApply.dll")] 
public static extern object ApplyNNet(string type, string add, double[] data);
```

**Update**

With this declaration you receive a pinvoke error:

> PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.

I'm not sure how you can get around this in pinvoke. In your situation I think I would create a VB6 project that wrapped up the DLL and exposed it as a COM interface. I'd then add a COM reference to your C# project and move on.

Comment: Does calling a C-ABI DLL function with `Variant` return type actually work at all? `Variant` is a COM interface, I don’t think those are supported by the C ABI in any way.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Sure. Variants can be used just fine from C, C++ etc. COM is accessible from C, C++. It's possible to write both sides of a COM interface in C. It's not much fun, but it is possible.

Comment: “can be used from … C++” and “are available in the C ABI” are two separate things. ;-) But the fact that COM is accessible in C (I didn’t know that!) is a dead giveaway that you’re right.

Comment: @David Hefferman: :D I correct these obvious differences, I changed the `double[,]` to `double` and the return value is `object`, but still there is an error: `PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.`

Comment: Hmm, now you are in trouble. Not sure how to solve that. It would help a lot if you had the original C++ header file for this DLL. If you have VB6 code that works, I'd be tempted to wrap that up in a COM wrapper and call that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just have a dll and no codes are available!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan `Declare Function ApplyNNet Lib " location of the DLL file" (MyNNetType As String, MyAddress As String, MyInput() As Double) As Variant` is correct VB6 syntax.

Comment: "First of all, I am assuming that the DLL was not in fact written in VB6. The fact that you show code that uses `Declare` to call the function contradicts that."

Comment: @Dan No it does not. `Declare` is used to import functions. That's different from implementing that function in VB6 which is as has been explained, not possible.

Comment: @David I just copy-pasted the opening paragraph of your answer and you disagreed with it :) . Consider editing it to be more clear. That is my point.

Comment: No, the opening paragraph is accurate. You have not understood it. The VB6 code is calling a DLL. That DLL was not written in VB6, as was erroneously claimed by the author of the question.

Comment: Actually, I don't care anymore. I've seen this question in 3 other forms, some of which have been closed for low quality. I'm going to try to ignore #5.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Couldn't you just force the variant issue with: `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=8)]
        struct MyVariant { ushort vt; ushort r1; ushort r2; ushort r3; UInt64 data; };` and then manually marshal the returned structure?  Of course, a C++ Interop layer would probably be the easier way out...

Comment: @ebyrob That would very likely fly, but your variant struct is not quite right. It needs to be bigger on x64. Anyway, C++/CLI is surely the way.